# Integral by the Trapezoidal rule algorithm I wrote is giving a 10 times larger answer

Tags: python, formula, integral

I made a function in Python which calculates a definite integral according to the Trapezoidal rule:
[Trapezoidal rule formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EnY5S.png)

That's the code:

```
from math import ceil

def Trapez_rule(f, a, b, n):
    '''Calculates an estimation of a definite integral of a function f(x), between the boundries a, b, by dividing the area to n equal areas'''
    sum = (f(a) + f(b)) / 2
    for i in range(ceil((b * n))):
        sum += f(a + i / n)
    sum *= (b - a) / n
    return sum
```

The answer it gives is 10 times higher that it should have returned.
I can't find the source of the problem.

Comment: Try printing during the for loop to see what is happening then you might find the issue yourself.

Comment: I did that now, due to your suggestion. I added the line "print(str(f(a + i / n)) + " " + str(sum))" to the loop. There is no way to know what numbers should appear there. also, the final result can't be understood from the loop, because later you multiply it by another number, and completely change the result.

Comment: Print the intermediate values on every step, or use a debugger. You will see where your assumptions break.

Answer (score 1):

Assume:

```
a=10
b=20
n=5
```

These lines are the problem:

```
for i in range(ceil((b * n))):
    sum += f(a + i / n)
```

`i` go from 0 to 99 
when i = 99 then:

```
f(a + i / n) => f(10 + 99/5) => f(29)
```

1. You divide two ints 99/5 => 29 and not 29.8.
2. But you only want to have it in range from 10 to 20.
3. You use n false look at the post solution below, so this should work:

   def Trapez_rule(f, a, b, n):
       h = (b-a) / float(n)
       sum = (f(a) + f(b)) / 2.w
       for i in range(1,n-1):
           sum += f(a + i * h)
       sum *= h
       return sum

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work. The result still aren't true. When trying other functions, sometimes the results weren't even 10 times larger than the real result, but just false, without any seem relation to the real result.

Comment: I edit my post^^ you divide two ints that was the second failure.
But it looks like something still is fishy... hmm

Comment: I edit again and this this works. when it don't works for you which numbers do you test with?

Answer (score 0):

I went ahead and fixed your code, and also renamed the function to fit with the official style guide [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-names).

```
def trapezium_rule_integral(f, a, b, n):
    '''Calculates an estimate of the definite integral of a function f, between
       the boundaries a and b, by dividing the area to n equal areas'''
    height = (b - a) / n
    x = a
    ys = []
    while x <= b:
        ys.append(f(x))
        x += height
    estimate = 0.5 * height * ( (ys[0] + ys[-1]) + 2 * (sum(ys[1:-1])) )
    return estimate
```